# How many ways to tie $2$ ropes so that we do not have a loop

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

BdMO 2014 Higher Secondary:

> Avik is holding six identical ropes in his hand where the mid portion of the rope is in his
>   fist. The first end of the ropes is lying in one side, and the other ends of the rope are lying
>   on another side. Kamrul randomly chooses the end points of the rope from one side, then tie
>   every two of them together. And then he did the same thing for the other end. If the
>   probability of creating a loop after tying all six rope is expressed as $\dfrac{a}b$, (where a, b are coprime) find the value of $(a+b)$.

There are $\dbinom{6}{2}$ possible pairs of ropes which we could tie.Also,the number of different ways to tie three pairs of ropes is $\dbinom{6}2\cdot\dbinom{4}2$ which is $90$.Hence the total number of ways to tie the ends on both sides(we will call these sides top and bottom) is $90\cdot 90$. Now,consider first tying the ends at the bottom.There are $\dbinom{6}{2}-3=12$ possible ways to tie the ropes at the top.Hence the total number of ways of not having any loop is $\dbinom{12}3\cdot90$.Hence,the probability of not having any loop is $\dfrac{2}{15}$.Thus the required probability is $\dfrac{13}{15}$ and the required sum is $28$. Am I right?

Comment: For a little less work you can assume WLOG that on one end, A is always tied to B, C is always tied to D, and E is always tied to F.  This gives a total of just 15 possible layouts.  But... I'm confused.  You're always ending up with no loose ends, so all ropes must eventually be part of a loop: one case has three loops, 6 cases have two loops, and the remaining 8 have one loop.  So, what do you mean by no loop?

Comment: I would translate "not having any loop" to "not having more than one loop" or "having exactly one big loop". A loop-less construction would require two unconnected rope-ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing what he did he has three ropes: $1,2,3$. Suppose he puts them on the table, He begins tying rope $1$, the probability he ties it with another rope is $\frac{4}{5}$ since there are $5$ other rope ends and only $1$ is the same rope. If it ties with another rope there are now two ropes, proceed to tie the rope that is not made up of two ropes, the probability it ties to the other rope is $\frac{2}{3}$ After this there are only two edges of one big rope and there is only one way to tie them. The probability is therefore $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{8}{15}$

Comment: Do you understand my solution?

Comment: Okay,I have just realized that I did not understand the question properly.I thought that having a loop meant that a pair of rope will be in a loop?Can you please explain the question to me?

Comment: Axel Kemper's comment is relevant. At the end there are going to be no lose ends. So all the ropes are going to be loops. The thing that can change is the number of loops. The question wants you to calculate the probability it is exactly one big loop.

Comment: Yes I understand your solution.It's nice.One question however.In your third sentence,you say 'If it ties with another rope there are now three ropes.'. Shouldn't there be two ropes?

Comment: Yes it should, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

What we'll do is, we'll let Kamrul tie the first three knots, and then label the ropes, and then let him tie the other three.  Thus no matter what ropes he chooses the first time, we can say he has tied A to B, C to D, and E to F.

The number of perfect matchings for $2n$ objects is $(2n-1)!!$, the [odd double factorials](http://oeis.org/A001147).  For six objects, this is $5!!=15$.  This is small enough that I can do it out by hand:

```
AB CD EF: three loops, AB CD EF
AB CE DF: two loops, AB CDFE
AB CF DE: two loops, AB CDEF
AC BD EF: two loops, ABDC EF
AC BE DF: one loop, ABEFDC
AC BF DE: one loop, ABFEDC
AD BC EF: two loops, ABCD EF
AD BE CF: one loop, ABEFCD
AD BF CE: one loop, ABFECD
AE BC DF: one loop, ABCDFE
AE BD CF: one loop, ABDCFE
AE BF CD: two loops, ABFE CD
AF BC DE: one loop, ABCDEF
AF BD CE: one loop, ABDCEF
AF BE CDL two loops, ABEF CD
```

So (assuming you are counting the ways that all of them will be in a single loop), there are 15 ways of tying the ropes, and 8 of those ways will create a single loop.